# Text content analytic test cases

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, functional, non-functional

I'm working on a project which is based on Text Content Analytic. It is actually analyzing given text content and we are presenting it in different output format like - PDF report, Graph in Dashboard. For this we are using one open source tools provided by Stanford University named [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#about).

There are basically two phases which generate output and are saved in DB.

1. KeyPhrase Analytics
2. Entity Analytic

As per development team they apply some algorithm on above two process to generate output and for that they are using `CoreNLP` jar file.
As I am new to the `CoreNLP`functionality, I initially have read content on the Stanford Site to actually get an idea about these two process so that I can write test cases to verify the Output and do the functional and Non-Functional testing.  But I don’t find such material for testing. It is all about the development\customization only.

1. Which kind of test data I should prepare to test this functionality?
2. Which kind of test scenario I have to define?
3. Is their any free tools available to test my output that it is proper & reliable?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how many people here know anything about "CoreNLP". To me it seems you are on the right track: e.g. *learning what it is*. Go from there.

You won't find copy/paste answers for your challenge. 
So ask yourself:

- what is it that I want to know about these functions?
- what do I know that function x should be doing?
- How could I check that thing that I want to know?
- What would happen if I did this?
- .... (the list is endless)

To quote Bolton&Bach: “Testing is the process of evaluating a product by learning about it through exploration and experimentation, which includes: questioning, study, modeling, observation and inference, output checking, etc.”

Welcome to the [testing](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/1509) world!